# Permissions denied

Tags: permissions, anaconda, kivy, toolchain

I'am trying to create a package for iOS with kivy.:https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

I try to run: `./toolchain.py build kivy` in terminal on mac.
Error: sudo: unable to execute ./toolchain.py: Permission denied.

My python is setup in anaconda and is running correctly.
In the first line of ./toolchain.py is: `#!/anaconda/envs/python2/bin python2.7`

Anyone knows how to change the permissions/how to get it to work?

When I set python to default: `/usr/bin/env` and adjust first line of ./toolchain.py it does execute, but in default python I'am not able to install pip.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure `./toolchain.py` got execution bit set (`chmod a+x toolchain.py`)

Comment: what are full file permissions?

Comment: read and write. When I run `ls -l ./toolchain.py` it gives me: _-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 myUserName  staff  48444_

Comment: also you said `I try to run: ./toolchain.py build kivy in terminal on mac. Error: sudo: unable to execute ./toolchain.py: Permission denied.` - where `sudo` comes from?

Comment: I meant I tried to run: `sudo ./toolchain.py build kivy`.