# Kivy-iOS toolchain wont run 'Permission Denied'

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, kivy

Im trying to convert a kivy app to run on iOS and have followed the information on the kivy site.  However, once everything is downloaded the first step is to compile the toolchain process, which I cant do.  So the command

```
./toolchain.py openssl kivy
```

returns

```
 ./toolchain.py: Permission denied
```

No other messages so a bit difficult to troubleshoot.  I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466935/permissions-denied).  That suggestion hasn't been accepted or marked as correct, but I tried anyway and changing permissions doesn't fix the problem.  I have tried

```
chmod a+x toolchain.py
sudo chmod 755 ./toolchain.py
sudo chmod 755 ./toolchain.py
```

All of which change the permissions as expected but trying to run toolchain now gives me

```
from: can't read /var/mail/kivy_ios.toolchain
./toolchain.py: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

So changing permission doesn't seem to work either and I'm now out of ideas???
Also for info I'm running kivy in a venv on Catalina

Answer (score 0):

So - it turns out after updating XCode you have to reselect the command line tools. Then it all works fine.

Comment: could you tell me what version of xcode you are running? my command line tools are set, yet I get the same error as you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for future users. If any of the above answers don't work.
Use this https://pypi.org/project/kivy-ios/ and follow all the instructions